# Is it possible to compile OCaml codes using Core without corebuild?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I have OCaml 4.05 installed (via apt-get) as well as  utop and [Core](https://github.com/janestreet/core) (via opam). And this is the content of my `~/.ocamlinit`:

```
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
```

Compiling OCaml codes which use Core works fine with corebuild. It doesn't work with plain ocamlc or ocamlopt though. They complain:

> Error: Unbound module Core

And I found corebuild to be pretty picky. It doesn't like any existing non-OCaml codes in the same directory:

```
SANITIZE: a total of 12 files that should probably not be in your source tree
  has been found. A script shell file "/home/anta40/Codes/_build/sanitize.sh"
  is being created. Check this script and run it to remove unwanted files or
  use other options (such as defining hygiene exceptions or using the
  -no-hygiene option).
IMPORTANT: I cannot work with leftover compiled files.
ERROR: Leftover object files:
  File hellod.o in . has suffix .o
  File helloscheme_.o in . has suffix .o
  File nqueens.o in . has suffix .o
  File helloscheme.o in . has suffix .o
  File HelloHS.o in . has suffix .o
  File helloml.o in . has suffix .o
ERROR: Leftover OCaml compilation files:
  File nqueens.cmo in . has suffix .cmo
  File helloml.cmo in . has suffix .cmo
  File helloml.cmi in . has suffix .cmi
  File nqueens.cmi in . has suffix .cmi
  File nqueens.cmx in . has suffix .cmx
  File helloml.cmx in . has suffix .cmx
Exiting due to hygiene violations.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

Using the `-no-hygiene` option, e.g `corebuild sum.ml -no-hygiene` doesn't produce any native executable. Is there any workaround?
 `

Answer (score 0):

The OPAM package manager can support multiple OCaml instances, where each groups an OCaml installation (`ocaml`, `ocamlc`, `ocamlopt`, etc.) with installed packages. Each instance is called a *switch*.

Type `ocaml switch` to see a list of instances. In terms of switches, the installation of OCaml using packages (apt-get) is called  *system*.

**It may be better to avoid mixing the system and OPAM installations.** I suggest that you create a new switch, ensure that the OPAM settings are properly sourced, and install Core into it the new switch :

```
opam switch 4.06.1
eval $(opam config env)
opam install core
```

The automatic build tools assume that they control the entire build process and complain when they find other compilation results. Normally, running the suggested shell script and retrying side-steps the problem, even if only to uncover another one. Your second problem (with `-no-hygeine`) may be related to the installation issues.

Comment: Hmm so that means I'll have 2 OCaml versions installed: 4.05 (via Ubuntu package manager), and 4.06.1 (via OPAM)?

Comment: Yes: one installed under `/usr/` and the other under `$HOME/.opam`. In my experience, it's worth a try. It seems to be a normal situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is dated.

I imagine that you followed instructions in Real World OCaml but OCaml ecosystem has moved since the first edition of RWO. To get a modern installation you should follow the dev version of Real World OCaml https://dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html .

To answer your question, corebuild is a fine wrapper around ocamlbuild. To build an executable from a `sum.ml` with corebuild, you should use

> corebuild sum.native

for native executable or

> corebuild sum.byte

for bytecode compilation

Otherwise, you can invoke ocamlopt through  ocamlfind:

> ocamlfind ocamlopt -package core sum.ml

Finally, if you intend to build larger project, you ought to have a look to dune https://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html .